# cursoradapter with different row layouts

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to create a custom cursoradapter that will use two different layouts depending on some data in the cursor. I keep reading about 'overriding getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType()' to make this happen but I can't seem to figure out how to implement this..

This is my code for the bindView and new View methods:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    tView.setText("The text");
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);
}
```

.

**EDIT:**
Now I got this working, but I want to choose what rowlayout to use depending on some data in the cursor and I can't get that working.. anybody got some ideas?

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.txtAddress
            .setText("blabla");
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    View v = null;
    int type = cursor.getPosition() % 2;
    if(type == 0) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false); 
    } else {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, parent, false);
    }

    holder.txtAddress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add sections/headers to your list view? Mark Murphy made a really easy to use cwac-merge list adapter that may help.

Comment: No, i have 2 different layouts and sometimes I want to use layout1 if mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("1") and I want to use layout2 when mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("2")

Comment: If you wanted, you could just grab two separate cursors.  One where type == 1 and one for where type == 2.  It's ghetto, but it may help you move forward.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

So I finally got it work. For the ones interested the working code is below:

```
private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
    String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
    if (type.equals("1")) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
    return getItemViewType(cursor);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.textView
            .setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    View v = null;

    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")).equals("1")) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.message1, parent, false);
        holder.textView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    } else {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.message2, parent, false);
        holder.textView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    v.setTag(holder);
    return v;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

Comment: getItem(position) calls moveToPosition(position) on the internal cursor object, and I suspect it to be a little too expensive to be called so often. Do you get it to scroll fluently with this in your app?

Comment: Yep scrolls fluently. Found code like this in the android source code.

Comment: @jagsler I am trying to achieve something similar, have you noticed a problem where while scrolling the view layouts get changed somehow?

Comment: @kabuto178 I had that same problem when I didn't override the getViewTypeCount() method.

Comment: @WilliamKenney actually that did fix it, but all this time I thought that would have not much effect, it seems the recycling of views have something to do with it

Comment: Finally an example of using multiple views in a cursor adapter. To me, key here was implementing
'getItemViewType'

Comment: You saved my nights! :) Thx

Comment: Without overriding `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` also my adapter is working as expected. So whats the use of them. i am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this [example](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296), you can easily adapt it for solving your problem. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think i understand (most part of) the code given in the example but I get confused at the point where I don't have a getView method but a newView and bindView method.. how can I implement the code given in the example in my case?

Comment: CursorAdapter has an implementation of getView() that delegates to newView() and bindView(), in such a way as enforces the row recycling pattern. So in newView(), you would create the ViewHolder for the row and associate it with setTag(). In bindView(), you would retrieve the ViewHolder via getTag(); at the end you just need to adapt/split the same logic between the 2 methods. Busy now, but I can write some code tonight in case you need...

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm going to try it myself first but I'll let you know if don't get it to work.

Comment: Gonna write some code tonight and I'll get back to you. Let me know if you make it work...

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Can you please help me out with the code?

Comment: Hey jagsler, I started but did not finish yet, pretty busy at work. I'll try to finish it...

Comment: I updated the code I got working for now. Still don't know how to make it work depending on some data in the cursor..

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution regarding the access to the cursor in the getItemViewType method is the following:

```
@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    Cursor c = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contract.MyColumn)).equals("value"))
        return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```