# Use a different view for the first row of a ListView backed by a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

Unfortunately, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8479833/1747491) didn't help because he is storing the type in the database.  I simply want the **first row** to be inflated with a different view than the rest.  You can't check `position`, like I see many answers suggest, because the `CursorAdapter` works differently than other adapters, for efficiency, and thus you will get multiple `position = 0` rows.

Comment: The `CursorAdapter` works like other adapters when dealing with different rows. For your case you just need to tell the adapter that you have 2 types of rows and also let it know that the first type corresponds only to position `0`, any other rows will have the other type of row. The code from the other question is almost what you need.

Comment: @Luksprog I think I am overlooking something.  I don't see where the conditional statement would happen to check for `first row`.